# sub Applescript with Global / property

Tags: applescript, environment-variables

I'll like to run a second applescript with variable from the first Applescript.

If I do a first script to

```
property myName : "Kevin"
```

And a second script with :

```
set remoteScript to (load script "/Users/kevin/Documents/Script/script1.scpt")

set myName to myName of remoteScript
```

Then everything is fine, the issue is ! The issue is my variable are generated on the first script and so, I can't use property.

I tried to use ***Global*** instead but I always having an error

My variables on my main script are mostly set (but not only) from Javascript, I used to use ***plist*** to store them but I'm curious and I'd like to try with a another way (also I have probably thousand of variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **property** is a bit different than a variable - it is more like a getter/setter declaration, where its usage performs the get/set handler of the specified script object and returns the result.

A **global** also has scope across script objects, but since it doesn’t have a value until one is assigned, you need to *run* the remote script to do that.  In addition, you should probably define the same variable(s) as global in your second script, for example:

First script:

```
property myName : "Kevin"
global test, one, more

doSomething() -- set globals

on doSomething()
  set test to "testing"
  set one to 1
  set more to {2, 3}
end doSomething
```

Second script:

```
global test, one, more

set remoteScript to (load script "/Users/you/path/to/First.scpt")
run remoteScript

log myName of remoteScript
log test
log one
log more
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to set `myName` as `property myName` then you could  set `property myName : missing value` then set its value with `set myName to myName of remoteScript`

```
property myName : missing value

set scriptLibrary to (path to documents folder as text) & "Script:script1.scpt"
set remoteScript to load script alias scriptLibrary

set myName to myName of remoteScript
```